# PowerShell - How to insert a colon character before the first backslash in a string?

Tags: string, powershell

In PowerShell I have a string with a value similar to :

```
> text/text/text\text\text\text
```

The string is variable length, and may have different numbers of forward and back slashes.

I want to insert a colon (`:`) character before the first backslash only.  So change it from ...

```
> text/text/text\text\text\text
```

to ...

```
> text/text/text:\text\text\text
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Loop through your string, character by character and check if the current character is '\'. If not, move on to the next (loop), if it is, assign the string the characters between [0] and whatever number your found, + ':' + the next char location to the end. Exit the loop.

Comment: Could you give an example of some specific code to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Insert()` and `IndexOf()` string methods:

```
$string = 'text/text/text\text\text\text'
$result = $string.Insert($string.IndexOf('\'),':')
```

---

[`String.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified string in this instance.

while [`String.Insert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Returns a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance.

---

With PowerShell 3.0+ you can also easily use regular expressions to insert the `:`:

```
$result = $string -replace '(?<!\\.*)\\',':\'
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest this but Mathias' answer is better:

```
$text = 'text/text/text\text\text\text'

$bs = $text.IndexOf('\')
"$($text.Substring(0,$bs)):$($text.Substring($bs))"
```